# C# NUnit testing using class library

Tags: c#, nunit, class-library

I am new NUnit and am having trouble accessing methods from my main project in my test project. Specifically the MyMath class.

main class

```
public class MyMath
{
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    public int Sub(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
}
```

test class

```
[TestFixture]
class MyTestCase
{
    [TestCase]
    public void Add()
    {
        MyMath math = new MyMath();
        Assert.AreEqual(31, math.Add(20, 11));
    }

    [TestCase]
    public void Sub()
    {
        MyMath math = new MyMath();
        Assert.AreEqual(10, math.Sub(20, 10));
    }
```

I have added references of the Main project to the Test Project how the prof specified
[image: Screenshot of Profs Spec] 
But still my references to the MyMath Class are not found 
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MyMath' could not be found

I used this tutorial to teach me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2NrKazjWes

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but it's not a namespace issue by chance?

Comment: No it is not i am just attempting to call the  'MyMath.cs' class which can't be found

Comment: are you missing a using directive at top for namespace of `MyMath`?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean, the only using statement I had added is: `using NUnit.Framework` @as.if.i.code

Comment: Then you need to include a `using` statement in NUnit's class file, to add reference to MyMath. Add using as - `using namespaceOfmyClass; ` at top.